# Переключение значений в справочнике наподобие радио кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, lambda

Как эффективно реализовать работу со справочником как с "радио кнопкой", при установке любого значения по ключу в `True`, остальные сбросить в `False`

Есть мысли что можно применить `map` и `lambda` но у самого не получилось.

```
dic = {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': False, 'k5': True}
dic['k3'] = True

print(dic)
```

Comment: все сбросьте в False, не разбираясь, k3 сделайте True

Comment: `newdic = {k: k == 'k3' for k in dic}`

Comment: Эффективно - не использовать словарь, а использовать список полей и индекс выбранного поля.

Comment: @insolor А если необходимы именованные ключи а не по индексу?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, тогда в словаре в значениях хранить индекс и сравнивать его с индексом выбранного поля.

Comment: @insolor Ничего не понятно, как ваш метод будет работать с индексами быстрее обычных констант True/False да и вообще как он будет работать, приведите пример, в воздухе он не очевиден.

Answer (score 3):

Несколько вариантов реализации на выбор

#### Вариант с хранением словаря с булевыми значениями:

Естественно, это не единственный вариант реализации. Здесь при переключении изменяется исходный словарь (нет накладных расходов на создание нового словаря, но при переключении нужно сбрасывать имеющееся истинные значения).

```
class SwitchDict:
    def __init__(self, keys, position=None):
        if position is None:
            position = keys[0]

        self._dict = {key: False for key in keys}
        self._dict[position] = True

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value:
            # Сначала нужно сбросить имеющееся истинное значение (значения)

            # Просто сбрасываем все значения в словаре, без проверок в цикле
            # (считаем, что в словаре исходно могло быть несколько истинных значений)
            for k in self._dict:
                self._dict[k] = False

            # Или идем до первого истинного значения и сбрасываем только его
            # (считаем что только одно значение истинно)
            #for k in self._dict:
            #    if self._dict[k]:
            #        self._dict[k] = False
            #        break

            self._dict[key] = True

    def as_dict(self):
        return self._dict

d = SwitchDict(['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5'])
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': True, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': False, 'k5': False}

d['k4'] = True
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': True, 'k5': False}

# Можно добавлять ключ, которого раньше не было в словаре
d['abc'] = True
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': False, 'k5': False, 'abc': True}
```

#### Храним ключи и текущую позицию (не сам словарь с булевыми значениями), два варианта:

Вариант с целочисленной позицией (компактный вариант, нет накладных расходов при переключении, но нельзя добавлять новые ключи (по крайней мере, в данной реализации)):

```
class SwitchDict:
    def __init__(self, keys, position=0):
        self._key_indices = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(keys)}
        self.position = position

    def as_dict(self):
        return {key: i==self.position for key, i in self._key_indices.items()}

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SwitchDict(keys={!r}, position={})'.format(list(self._key_indices.keys()), self.position)


d = SwitchDict(['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5'], position=3)
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': True, 'k5': False}

d.position = 4
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': False, 'k5': True}
```

Вариант со строковой позицией:

```
class SwitchDict:
    def __init__(self, keys, position=None):
        if position is None:
            position = keys[0]

        self._keys = set(keys)

        self.set_position(position)

    def set_position(self, position):
        if position not in self._keys:
            self._keys.add(position)

        self._position = position

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value:
            self.set_position(key)

    def as_dict(self):
        return {key: key==self._position for key in self._keys}

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SwitchDict(keys={!r}, position={!r})'.format(self._keys, self._position)


d = SwitchDict(['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5'])
print(d)  # SwitchDict(keys=['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5'], position='k1')
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': True, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': False, 'k5': False}

d.set_position('k3')
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': True, 'k4': False, 'k5': False}

# Можно добавлять ключ, которого раньше не было в словаре
d.set_position('abc')
print(d.as_dict())  # {'k1': False, 'k2': False, 'k3': False, 'k4': False, 'k5': False, 'abc': True}
```

2 и 3 варианты лучше тем, что нет накладных расходов при переключении позиции. Зато есть накладные расходы при получении готового словаря (в первом варианте сразу возвращается существующий словарь).